# Testing significance of correlation between two autocorrelated series

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, autocorrelation

Say I collected the shin bones of *N* different skeletons; they are all around 30cm long, and I measured different properties P1, P2, P3, P4 and P5 along these bones every 3mm (so I have 100 data points for each P) to see how well they measure bone density. I also measured the amount *F* of fungus along these bones (every 3mm as well).

I am especially interested in P5, which seems a pretty good indicator of bone density, and I want to see how well P1, P2, P3 and P4 are correlated with P5. I would like to have 1) a global measure of correlation between each P and P5 taking into account the measures along the whole bone (with significance test). Since the bone density varies in a particular way (non-linear, non cyclic, ...), and the amount of fungus can influence the other P, I would also be very interested in calculating 2) the local correlation (say along 3cm segment) between each P and P5 along the bone.

The problem for 1) is that all the series are autocorrelated (since all the properties vary slowly in space). I would have done a simple cross-correlation, but then the p-value would need correction for the fact that the series are autocorrelated. Then what can I do? And should I average the values of all skeletons at each point along the bone before computing the correlation?

For 2) I was thinking of calculating a "running/moving correlation" on a window, say 10-points long (3cm) so as to have a measure of correlation at each point. Then I would not only have to take into account the autocorrelation; I would also have to correct for the multiple testing caused by a "running/moving correlation". Any idea on how I could do this (Bonferroni corrections would be too conservative)?

One of the things I would like to show for the running/moving correlation (but not only) is that low values of correlation between P1, P2, ..., P4 and P5 are obtained when the fungus measure *F* is high (just saying).

I use R, but I am a beginner in statistics, so I would be grateful if you could take that into account in your answer :) 
Thanks.

P.S. I am not studying bones, but that seems a simpler story.

Comment: This sounds like a great use case for Vector Autoregression (VAR).

Comment: The value at position X-1 of the property Pi is not assumed to influence P5 more than the value of Pi at X (no spatial causality and no lag, the series are "synchronized"). So would Vector Autoregression still be well adapted for this problem?

Comment: No, I misunderstood. There are a few ways to correct for autocorrelation in time series (Cochrane-Orcutt, Prais-Winsten, Newey-West) and a few ways to correct for error clustering by bone (see a write-up I just made here: http://www.columbia.edu/~gw2286/clustering_demo.html), but I'm not sure if there are special considerations in combining them.

Comment: Thanks, i will look into correcting for autocorrelation. I am not clustering by bone (i'm looking at the same bone in different individuals assumed to be from the same population). It is still not very clear to me which steps i should follow to obtain 1) a general correlation measure of Pi <-> P5 with significance test and 2) a moving correlation measure of Pi <-> P5 with significance test

Comment: I re-read your post and, again, I think I'm misunderstanding you. You're just looking for pairwise correlations, e.g. the correlation between P4 and P5, so forget regression. Could you maybe clarify what you mean by "local" and "global"? What's wrong with just taking the correlation between time series? It doesn't matter that the series themselves are nonlinear, it only matters that their relationship is linear. Or you could use distance correlation to measure statistical dependence.

Comment: Sure, i'll clarify, thanks for your help:
- by global i meant correlation of the whole series
- by local i meant correlation restricted to the window of the moving/running correlation
The problem of taking the correlation between time series is that the associated significance testing would need to be corrected for the auto-correlation in the series themselves and i do not know what would be the simplest way to do this.
And regression could actually be interesting if i could explain P4 behavior with both P5 and F for example.